# Why are nested mocha test suites not run when mocha is run with --recursive flag

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Following mocha nested test suite structure is run as expected with:
`mocha --timeout 25000 test.js`

```
describe('test suite 1', function() {
  it('unit test 1', (done) => {

    describe('test suite 2', function() {
      it('unit test 2') {

        describe('test suite 3', function() {
          it('unit test 3') {
```

I don't see why this isn't the case when test are run with:
`mocha --recursive --timeout 25000`

Looking in debug log I can clearly see that `it 2` and `it 3` are not run. I have to use `mocha --recursive --timeout 25000` as I have more test suite files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The structure you are showing in your question is not supported by Mocha. To cover the various cases:

- `describe` inside `describe`? Fine.
- `it` inside `describe`? Fine.
- `describe` inside `it`? Mocha does not support this. The results are undefined. If you get the results you expect, that's due to luck.
- `it` inside `it`? Again, not supported by Mocha. The results are undefined.

Comment: You are right. I have pulled **describe** block out of **it** block and it works as expected for me.